# Any way to upload a file to sharepoint through webservice

Tags: sharepoint, soap, file-upload, sharepoint-2010

I have a requirement to upload files to sharepoint using sharepoint webservices. 
Are there any sharepoint services which consumes the file content as base64 data inside soap request?

Comment: [Uploading Content Into SharePoint](http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.in/2009/09/uploading-content-into-sharepoint-let.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for a simple soap request which can do the job, and with the help of comments from @ElvisLikeBear I was able to make use of the CopyIntoItems web service in http://server/sites/personal/_vti_bin/copy.asmx.

```
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP:Body>
    <CopyIntoItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <SourceUrl>fileName.ext</SourceUrl>
      <DestinationUrls>
        <string>{your share point location to where the file has to be uploaded.}http://mySharepoint/mysharepointsite/fileName.ext</string>
      </DestinationUrls>
      <Fields>
        <!--FieldInformation Type="Note" DisplayName="CustomerMeta_0" InternalName="" Id="12345678-4564-9875-1236-326598745623" Value="xxx" /-->
      </Fields>
      <Stream>Base 64 encoded content </Stream>
    </CopyIntoItems>
  </SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>
```

Comment: FieldInformation tag carries the metadata , its not mandatory

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://cecildt.blogspot.com.au/2010/10/upload-documents-to-sharepoint-2010.html) resource will help you to understand this.

Here's the relevant content from the article in case the link is broken for future readers:

> Let’s Upload a Document
>
> To upload a document we need to add another service reference to
>   http://server/sites/personal/_vti_bin/copy.asmx. This is the Copy
>   service.
>
> Here is the code to upload a document to the document library:

```
 CopySoapClient client = new CopySoapClient();

 if (client.ClientCredentials != null)
 {
     client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
 }

 try
 {
     client.Open();
     string url = "http://server/sites/personal/My Documents Library/Folder One/Folder Two/";
     string fileName = "test.txt";
     string[] destinationUrl = { url + fileName };
     byte[] content = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

     // Description Information Field
     FieldInformation descInfo = new FieldInformation
                                     {
                                         DisplayName = "Description",
                                         Type = FieldType.Text,
                                         Value = "Test file for upload"
                                     };

     FieldInformation[] fileInfoArray = { descInfo };

     CopyResult[] arrayOfResults;

     uint result = client.CopyIntoItems(fileName, destinationUrl, fileInfoArray, content, out arrayOfResults);
     Trace.WriteLine("Upload Result: " + result);

     // Check for Errors
     foreach (CopyResult copyResult in arrayOfResults)
     {
         string msg = "====================================" +
                      "SharePoint Error:" +
                      "\nUrl: " + copyResult.DestinationUrl +
                      "\nError Code: " + copyResult.ErrorCode +
                      "\nMessage: " + copyResult.ErrorMessage +
                      "====================================";

         Trace.WriteLine(msg);
         _logFactory.ErrorMsg(msg);
     }
 }
 finally
 {
     if (client.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
     {
         client.Abort();
     }

     if (client.State != CommunicationState.Closed)
     {
         client.Close();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Spservises to achieve the desired functionality. Please see the code below:

```
function UploadFile(listName,itemId,files){
    var filereader = {},
        file = {};
    var fileLength = files.length;
    //loop over each file selected
    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) 
    {
        file = files[i];            
        filereader = new FileReader();          
        filereader.filename = file.name;
        filereader.onload = function() {                
            var data = this.result,                     
                n=data.indexOf(";base64,") + 8;             
            //removing the first part of the dataurl give us the base64 bytes we need to feed to sharepoint
            data= data.substring(n);
            $().SPServices({
                operation: "AddAttachment",                 
                listName: listName,
                asynch: true,
                listItemID:itemId,
                fileName: this.filename,
                attachment: data,
                completefunc: testFunction(i,fileLength)
                            });                 
        };
        filereader.onabort = function() {
            alert("The upload was aborted.");
        };

        filereader.onerror = function() {
            alert("An error occured while reading the file.");
        };              

        //fire the onload function giving it the dataurl
        filereader.readAsDataURL(file); 

    }
```

Here `files` is the files returned by using a html file control to upload.